# Group the ones that are the same and right next to each other in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, grouping

This is my table:

| websit_id | updated_at | display_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1222 | 03-06 06:00 | apple |
| 1222 | 03-06 08:00 | apple |
| 1222 | 03-06 10:00 | carrot |
| 1222 | 03-06 12:00 | apple |
| 1222 | 03-06 14:00 | fig |
| 1234 | 03-06 06:00 | apple |
| 1234 | 03-06 08:00 | peach |

I want to label the rows so that it groups the same display ID that are right next to each other but would not group them if there's something else in btw.

The desired output should be the following:

| websit_id | updated_at | display_id | group_label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1222 | 03-06 06:00 | apple | 1 |
| 1222 | 03-06 08:00 | apple | 1 |
| 1222 | 03-06 10:00 | carrot | 2 |
| 1222 | 03-06 12:00 | apple | 3 |
| 1222 | 03-06 14:00 | fig | 4 |
| 1234 | 03-06 06:00 | apple | 1 |
| 1234 | 03-06 08:00 | peach | 2 |

I am using snowflake for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a flag to indicate if the current display_id is the same as the previous one and then run a cumulative sum over it to create groups

```
with cte as

(select *, case when display_id = lag(display_id) over (partition by websit_id order by updated_at) then 0 else 1 end as flag
from mytable)

select *, sum(flag) over (partition by websit_id order by updated_at) as group_label --add 1 if you want groups to start at 1 instead of 0
from cte;
```

Comment: Your cumulative sums should start with 1, so maybe add 1 to the rolling sum.

Comment: I think the cte should be this instead:

(select *, case when display_id = lag(display_id) over (partition by websit_id order by updated_at) then 0 else 1 end as flag
from mytable)

Comment: @Zichaun Yeah I had it the other way, it's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem in disguise.  Your requirement is to form islands of like `display_id` within each group of `websit_id`, and then rank using the timestamp.  Here is one approach using the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY websit_id ORDER BY updated_at) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY websit_id, display_id ORDER BY updated_at) rn2
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, MAX(updated_at) OVER (PARTITION BY websit_id, display_id, rn1 - rn2) AS max_updated_at
    FROM cte1
)

SELECT websit_id, updated_at, display_id,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY websit_id ORDER BY max_updated_at DESC) AS group_label
FROM cte2
ORDER BY websit_id, updated_at DESC;
```